# How to change id value iterating by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html:

```
<div class="info">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Title</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8">
                <input id="titleInfo" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title">
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default remove_field"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Text</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8">
            <textarea id="textInfo" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Into my jsp I have many of this:

```
<div class="info">
    ...
</div>
<div class="info">
    ...
</div>
<div class="info">
    ...
</div>
```

Now, I would change the id tags: *titleInfo* and *textInfo* of every div with class *info* in ascending order.

```
<div class="info">
    ..<input id="titleInfo1"..
    ..<textarea id="textInfo1"..
</div>
<div class="info">
    ..<input id="titleInfo2"..
    ..<textarea id="textInfo2"..
</div>
<div class="info">
    ..<input id="titleInfo3"..
    ..<textarea id="textInfo3"..
</div>
```

and so on.

I thought to iterate by class *info*:

```
var x = 1;
$(".info").each(function() {
    //Now, I don't know how to change the ids
    x++;       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the code to following

```
var x = 1;
$(".info").each(function() {
    var elems = $(this).find(".form-control"); // get all the input elements with class form-control
    elems.each(function() { // iterate over the elements
         $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + x); // update id
    }); 
    x++;       
});
```

**Update**

```
var x = 1;
    $(".info").each(function() {
        var elems = $(this).find(".form-control"); // get all the input elements with class form-control
        $(elems[0]).attr("id", "titleInfo" + x);
        $(elems[1]).attr("id", "textInfo" + x);
        x++;       
    });
```

Comment: But I want that *titleInfo* was substituted with *titleInfo+x*. The same with *textInfo*. I tried with `$(this).attr('titleInfo', $(this).attr('titleInfo') + x);`, but it does not works

Comment: you are doing it wrong. titleInfo is the value not attribute. Attribute is id. Did you tried by updating code with the above?

Comment: Sorry, you're right.
Yes, I did. But it doesn't work. Let me explain why I want to modify the id. When page loads, jQuery generate many `<div class="info"></div>` that has *titleInfo* and *textInfo* in this way: first div has titleInfo1 and textInfo1, second div has titleInfo2 and textInfo2. I add a function that delete the div that I want. So, when I delete one div, I must reorder all ids of all div. Can this help you?

Comment: Sorry, last question: If I want disable, for example, the input with id=titleInfo1 I tried with `$("#titleInfo1").prop('disabled', true);` but not works.. Why? **UPDATE** Solved

Answer (score 0):

You should really do this server side, within the loop control you have that generates those blocks. For the sake of answering, here you go.

```
$(".info").each(function(index) {

    var $title = $(this).find("#titleInfo");
    var $text = $(this).find("#textInfo");
    $title[0].id += (index+1);
    $text[0].id += (index+1);
});
```

Take a [look at this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yndymm9t/) as well.

Comment: I have this error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined*. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code snippet.

```js
var x = 1;
$(".info").each(function() {
 var ele=$(this).find('.form-control');
  ele.each(function(){
     setId($(this),x)
   })
    x++;       
});

function setId(ele,x){
  ele.attr('id',ele.attr('id')+x)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Title</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8">
                <input id="titleInfo" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title">
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default remove_field"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Text</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8">
            <textarea id="textInfo" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="..."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This also does the same.

> Script

```
var x = 1;
$(".info").each(function() {
 var ele=$(this).find('.form-control');
  ele.each(function(){
      $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id')+x)
   })
    x++;       
});
```